# ActivationException when I try to use RequestNavigate

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef, invalidoperationexception

SI have a problem in a small application. It's only switching from a view to another, but it gives me this although it's very simple:

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' in Prism.Mef.Wpf.dll
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Prism.Wpf.dll

I (only) use

`this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, "testChangeView.Views.uC");`
to navigate, and the `RegionManager` is instantiated in somewhere else which I can't access (but at least I'm sure that it's not the problem).

What can be the cause? It was working fine yesterday.
Thanks!

Comment: Inner Exception?

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.

My application is separated in two modules, and one of them was using "Microsoft.Prism.*" instead of just "Prism.*".